# Pandas rolling.mean is returning unexpected values

Tags: python, pandas

My ultimate goal is to plot a time series of a variable vs. its 10-day moving average.

Here's the data set:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

the_data = """
A,2016-6-9 0:00,95
A,2016-6-10 0:00,0
A,2016-6-11 0:00,0
A,2016-6-12 0:00,0
A,2016-6-13 0:00,0
A,2016-6-14 0:00,0
A,2016-6-15 0:00,0
A,2016-6-16 0:00,0
A,2016-6-17 0:00,0
A,2016-6-18 0:00,0
A,2016-6-19 0:00,0
A,2016-6-20 0:00,0
A,2016-6-21 0:00,0
A,2016-6-22 0:00,0
A,2016-6-23 0:00,0
A,2016-6-24 0:00,0
A,2016-6-25 0:00,0
A,2016-6-26 0:00,0
A,2016-6-27 0:00,0
A,2016-6-28 0:00,0
A,2016-6-29 0:00,0
A,2016-6-30 0:00,28
A,2016-7-1 0:00,0
A,2016-7-2 0:00,0
A,2016-7-3 0:00,0
A,2016-7-4 0:00,0
A,2016-7-5 0:00,0
A,2016-7-6 0:00,0
A,2016-7-7 0:00,0
A,2016-7-8 0:00,0
A,2016-7-9 0:00,0
A,2016-7-10 0:00,0
A,2016-7-11 0:00,0
A,2016-7-12 0:00,0
A,2016-7-13 0:00,0
A,2016-7-14 0:00,92
A,2016-7-15 0:00,0
A,2016-7-16 0:00,0
A,2016-7-17 0:00,0
A,2016-7-18 0:00,100
A,2016-7-19 0:00,0
A,2016-7-20 0:00,0
A,2016-7-21 0:00,0
A,2016-7-22 0:00,0
A,2016-7-23 0:00,0
A,2016-7-24 0:00,0
A,2016-7-25 0:00,0
A,2016-7-26 0:00,18
A,2016-7-27 0:00,4
A,2016-7-28 0:00,38
A,2016-7-29 0:00,0
A,2016-7-30 0:00,0
A,2016-7-31 0:00,0
A,2016-8-1 0:00,29
A,2016-8-2 0:00,0
A,2016-8-3 0:00,0
A,2016-8-4 0:00,10
A,2016-8-5 0:00,0
A,2016-8-6 0:00,0
A,2016-8-7 0:00,0
A,2016-8-8 0:00,0
A,2016-8-9 0:00,0
A,2016-8-10 0:00,11
A,2016-8-11 0:00,40
A,2016-8-12 0:00,3
A,2016-8-13 0:00,0
A,2016-8-14 0:00,0
A,2016-8-15 0:00,25
A,2016-8-16 0:00,99
A,2016-8-17 0:00,60
A,2016-8-18 0:00,80
A,2016-8-19 0:00,65
A,2016-8-20 0:00,0
A,2016-8-21 0:00,0
A,2016-8-22 0:00,35
A,2016-8-23 0:00,68
A,2016-8-24 0:00,52
A,2016-8-25 0:00,26
A,2016-8-26 0:00,88
A,2016-8-27 0:00,0
A,2016-8-28 0:00,0
A,2016-8-29 0:00,15
A,2016-8-30 0:00,75
A,2016-8-31 0:00,29
A,2016-9-1 0:00,13
A,2016-9-2 0:00,37
A,2016-9-3 0:00,0
A,2016-9-4 0:00,0
A,2016-9-5 0:00,0
A,2016-9-6 0:00,75
A,2016-9-7 0:00,66
A,2016-9-8 0:00,58
A,2016-9-9 0:00,49
A,2016-9-10 0:00,0
A,2016-9-11 0:00,0
A,2016-9-12 0:00,46
A,2016-9-13 0:00,62
A,2016-9-14 0:00,39
A,2016-9-15 0:00,2
A,2016-9-16 0:00,75
B,2016-6-9 0:00,77
B,2016-6-10 0:00,70
B,2016-6-11 0:00,0
B,2016-6-12 0:00,80
B,2016-6-13 0:00,12
B,2016-6-14 0:00,45
B,2016-6-15 0:00,44
B,2016-6-16 0:00,55
B,2016-6-17 0:00,75
B,2016-6-18 0:00,0
B,2016-6-19 0:00,24
B,2016-6-20 0:00,50
B,2016-6-21 0:00,84
B,2016-6-22 0:00,27
B,2016-6-23 0:00,54
B,2016-6-24 0:00,50
B,2016-6-25 0:00,0
B,2016-6-26 0:00,67
B,2016-6-27 0:00,79
B,2016-6-28 0:00,95
B,2016-6-29 0:00,75
B,2016-6-30 0:00,82
B,2016-7-1 0:00,12
B,2016-7-2 0:00,0
B,2016-7-3 0:00,99
B,2016-7-4 0:00,47
B,2016-7-5 0:00,12
B,2016-7-6 0:00,9
B,2016-7-7 0:00,28
B,2016-7-8 0:00,100
B,2016-7-9 0:00,0
B,2016-7-10 0:00,70
B,2016-7-11 0:00,96
B,2016-7-12 0:00,98
B,2016-7-13 0:00,49
B,2016-7-14 0:00,10
B,2016-7-15 0:00,56
B,2016-7-16 0:00,0
B,2016-7-17 0:00,23
B,2016-7-18 0:00,44
B,2016-7-19 0:00,16
B,2016-7-20 0:00,72
B,2016-7-21 0:00,66
B,2016-7-22 0:00,41
B,2016-7-23 0:00,0
B,2016-7-24 0:00,88
B,2016-7-25 0:00,35
B,2016-7-26 0:00,100
B,2016-7-27 0:00,66
B,2016-7-28 0:00,5
B,2016-7-29 0:00,78
B,2016-7-30 0:00,0
B,2016-7-31 0:00,78
B,2016-8-1 0:00,50
B,2016-8-2 0:00,16
B,2016-8-3 0:00,80
B,2016-8-4 0:00,7
B,2016-8-5 0:00,44
B,2016-8-6 0:00,0
B,2016-8-7 0:00,33
B,2016-8-8 0:00,81
B,2016-8-9 0:00,56
B,2016-8-10 0:00,47
B,2016-8-11 0:00,66
B,2016-8-12 0:00,60
B,2016-8-13 0:00,0
B,2016-8-14 0:00,19
B,2016-8-15 0:00,44
B,2016-8-16 0:00,86
B,2016-8-17 0:00,66
B,2016-8-18 0:00,65
B,2016-8-19 0:00,41
B,2016-8-20 0:00,0
B,2016-8-21 0:00,92
B,2016-8-22 0:00,86
B,2016-8-23 0:00,4
B,2016-8-24 0:00,69
B,2016-8-25 0:00,29
B,2016-8-26 0:00,24
B,2016-8-27 0:00,0
B,2016-8-28 0:00,51
B,2016-8-29 0:00,71
B,2016-8-30 0:00,80
B,2016-8-31 0:00,32
B,2016-9-1 0:00,19
B,2016-9-2 0:00,6
B,2016-9-3 0:00,0
B,2016-9-4 0:00,77
B,2016-9-5 0:00,100
B,2016-9-6 0:00,1
B,2016-9-7 0:00,74
B,2016-9-8 0:00,87
B,2016-9-9 0:00,52
B,2016-9-10 0:00,0
B,2016-9-11 0:00,100
B,2016-9-12 0:00,22
B,2016-9-13 0:00,75
B,2016-9-14 0:00,100
B,2016-9-15 0:00,8
B,2016-9-16 0:00,3
C,2016-6-9 0:00,76
C,2016-6-10 0:00,0
C,2016-6-11 0:00,0
C,2016-6-12 0:00,0
C,2016-6-13 0:00,1
C,2016-6-14 0:00,44
C,2016-6-15 0:00,53
C,2016-6-16 0:00,87
C,2016-6-17 0:00,0
C,2016-6-18 0:00,0
C,2016-6-19 0:00,0
C,2016-6-20 0:00,13
C,2016-6-21 0:00,10
C,2016-6-22 0:00,17
C,2016-6-23 0:00,30
C,2016-6-24 0:00,2
C,2016-6-25 0:00,0
C,2016-6-26 0:00,0
C,2016-6-27 0:00,5
C,2016-6-28 0:00,40
C,2016-6-29 0:00,79
C,2016-6-30 0:00,28
C,2016-7-1 0:00,14
C,2016-7-2 0:00,0
C,2016-7-3 0:00,0
C,2016-7-4 0:00,76
C,2016-7-5 0:00,84
C,2016-7-6 0:00,26
C,2016-7-7 0:00,46
C,2016-7-8 0:00,46
C,2016-7-9 0:00,0
C,2016-7-10 0:00,0
C,2016-7-11 0:00,91
C,2016-7-12 0:00,62
C,2016-7-13 0:00,35
C,2016-7-14 0:00,0
C,2016-7-15 0:00,69
C,2016-7-16 0:00,0
C,2016-7-17 0:00,0
C,2016-7-18 0:00,95
C,2016-7-19 0:00,0
C,2016-7-20 0:00,19
C,2016-7-21 0:00,0
C,2016-7-22 0:00,90
C,2016-7-23 0:00,0
C,2016-7-24 0:00,0
C,2016-7-25 0:00,24
C,2016-7-26 0:00,8
C,2016-7-27 0:00,29
C,2016-7-28 0:00,23
C,2016-7-29 0:00,80
C,2016-7-30 0:00,0
C,2016-7-31 0:00,0
C,2016-8-1 0:00,9
C,2016-8-2 0:00,79
C,2016-8-3 0:00,19
C,2016-8-4 0:00,70
C,2016-8-5 0:00,85
C,2016-8-6 0:00,0
C,2016-8-7 0:00,0
C,2016-8-8 0:00,27
C,2016-8-9 0:00,0
C,2016-8-10 0:00,95
C,2016-8-11 0:00,8
C,2016-8-12 0:00,6
C,2016-8-13 0:00,0
C,2016-8-14 0:00,0
C,2016-8-15 0:00,31
C,2016-8-16 0:00,18
C,2016-8-17 0:00,47
C,2016-8-18 0:00,56
C,2016-8-19 0:00,4
C,2016-8-20 0:00,0
C,2016-8-21 0:00,0
C,2016-8-22 0:00,27
C,2016-8-23 0:00,17
C,2016-8-24 0:00,50
C,2016-8-25 0:00,0
C,2016-8-26 0:00,99
C,2016-8-27 0:00,0
C,2016-8-28 0:00,0
C,2016-8-29 0:00,81
C,2016-8-30 0:00,89
C,2016-8-31 0:00,47
C,2016-9-1 0:00,31
C,2016-9-2 0:00,94
C,2016-9-3 0:00,0
C,2016-9-4 0:00,0
C,2016-9-5 0:00,31
C,2016-9-6 0:00,2
C,2016-9-7 0:00,31
C,2016-9-8 0:00,23
C,2016-9-9 0:00,75
C,2016-9-10 0:00,0
C,2016-9-11 0:00,0
C,2016-9-12 0:00,92
C,2016-9-13 0:00,89
C,2016-9-14 0:00,91
C,2016-9-15 0:00,44
C,2016-9-16 0:00,0
D,2016-6-9 0:00,0
D,2016-6-10 0:00,0
D,2016-6-11 0:00,0
D,2016-6-12 0:00,0
D,2016-6-13 0:00,0
D,2016-6-14 0:00,0
D,2016-6-15 0:00,0
D,2016-6-16 0:00,0
D,2016-6-17 0:00,0
D,2016-6-18 0:00,0
D,2016-6-19 0:00,0
D,2016-6-20 0:00,0
D,2016-6-21 0:00,0
D,2016-6-22 0:00,0
D,2016-6-23 0:00,0
D,2016-6-24 0:00,0
D,2016-6-25 0:00,0
D,2016-6-26 0:00,0
D,2016-6-27 0:00,0
D,2016-6-28 0:00,0
D,2016-6-29 0:00,0
D,2016-6-30 0:00,0
D,2016-7-1 0:00,0
D,2016-7-2 0:00,0
D,2016-7-3 0:00,0
D,2016-7-4 0:00,0
D,2016-7-5 0:00,0
D,2016-7-6 0:00,0
D,2016-7-7 0:00,0
D,2016-7-8 0:00,0
D,2016-7-9 0:00,0
D,2016-7-10 0:00,0
D,2016-7-11 0:00,0
D,2016-7-12 0:00,0
D,2016-7-13 0:00,0
D,2016-7-14 0:00,0
D,2016-7-15 0:00,0
D,2016-7-16 0:00,0
D,2016-7-17 0:00,26
D,2016-7-18 0:00,96
D,2016-7-19 0:00,93
D,2016-7-20 0:00,58
D,2016-7-21 0:00,17
D,2016-7-22 0:00,34
D,2016-7-23 0:00,0
D,2016-7-24 0:00,82
D,2016-7-25 0:00,99
D,2016-7-26 0:00,46
D,2016-7-27 0:00,61
D,2016-7-28 0:00,100
D,2016-7-29 0:00,21
D,2016-7-30 0:00,0
D,2016-7-31 0:00,18
D,2016-8-1 0:00,98
D,2016-8-2 0:00,74
D,2016-8-3 0:00,31
D,2016-8-4 0:00,11
D,2016-8-5 0:00,78
D,2016-8-6 0:00,0
D,2016-8-7 0:00,75
D,2016-8-8 0:00,26
D,2016-8-9 0:00,35
D,2016-8-10 0:00,54
D,2016-8-11 0:00,82
D,2016-8-12 0:00,83
D,2016-8-13 0:00,0
D,2016-8-14 0:00,72
D,2016-8-15 0:00,49
D,2016-8-16 0:00,46
D,2016-8-17 0:00,63
D,2016-8-18 0:00,54
D,2016-8-19 0:00,69
D,2016-8-20 0:00,0
D,2016-8-21 0:00,87
D,2016-8-22 0:00,76
D,2016-8-23 0:00,20
D,2016-8-24 0:00,9
D,2016-8-25 0:00,21
D,2016-8-26 0:00,78
D,2016-8-27 0:00,0
D,2016-8-28 0:00,96
D,2016-8-29 0:00,76
D,2016-8-30 0:00,84
D,2016-8-31 0:00,73
D,2016-9-1 0:00,88
D,2016-9-2 0:00,93
D,2016-9-3 0:00,0
D,2016-9-4 0:00,57
D,2016-9-5 0:00,15
D,2016-9-6 0:00,71
D,2016-9-7 0:00,81
D,2016-9-8 0:00,52
D,2016-9-9 0:00,9
D,2016-9-10 0:00,0
D,2016-9-11 0:00,2
D,2016-9-12 0:00,15
D,2016-9-13 0:00,32
D,2016-9-14 0:00,47
D,2016-9-15 0:00,56
D,2016-9-16 0:00,11"""
```

**ADDING**:

First, create a data frame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data), header=None)
```

Now, add some column headers:

```
df.columns = ['Company', 'Date', 'Value']
```

**ADDING**: Then, convert the dates to a datetime object:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce')
```

Next, create a new column, which can be used to filter out weekends:

```
df['Day_of_Week'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday_name
```

Then, drop all rows that have the 'Day_of_Week' == Saturday or Sunday (because we don't want zero values included in the moving average):

```
df = df.loc[(df.Day_of_Week <> 'Saturday') & (df.Day_of_Week <> 'Sunday')]
```

Next, add a **trailing 10-day moving average** column that we'll use for our plot time series plot (note: this line of code is probably causing all of the issues!!):

```
df['Trade_Count_MA'] = (df.groupby('Company', as_index=False).rolling(window=10, min_periods=1, center=True).Value.mean().shift().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Let's visualize the data frame:

```
df.head(20)

df.tail(20)
```

I have several questions:

1) In index #12, why do we see a value of 2.8 in the 'Value_MA' column?  Given that Company A does not have a non-zero value until index #21 (with the exception of index #0), I would expect the value in index #11 to be zero.  Clearly, the value in index #21 is being divided by 10 and then being 'back-populated' in the 'Value_MA' column for the previous 8 records.  But, why?

2) Why are there 'NaN' values in the 'Value_MA' column for indices #288 to #399?  Are these values influenced by the zero values for Company D beginning at index # 299?  If so, how do I fix this?

3) Why do I see a value of 67.1 in the 'Value_MA' column for index # 84?  I would expect the following:

sum the values for indices # 70 through # 83, then divide by 10.  So,

80 + 65 + 35 + 68 + 52 + 26 + 88 + 15 + 75 + 29 = 533
533 / 10 = 53.3 (not 67.1)

How would we amend the code to reflect these values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you need `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data), header=None, parse_dates=[1])` before adding the columns?

Comment: @ayhan - yes, I agree.  But, introducing that line of code does not change the output.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest a solution. Your code currently does not run. I guessed that line would be necessary for a reproducible example.

Comment: I added a line of code that creates the data frame.  I can run this code with no problem.  Do you get an error message of some sort?